# TailwindCSS width does not set to the value that I give them

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

```
type Props = {
  img: string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  color: string;
};

export default function CardComponent({
  img,
  title,
  content,
  color,
}: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`container bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Page.tsx

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="flex flex-nowrap p-5 gap-5">
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <CardComponent
            key={post.title}
            img={post.img}
            title={post.title}
            content={post.content}
            color={post.color}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-nowrap p-5 gap-5">
        <div className={`container bg-orange-700  w-[300px] h-[300px]`}></div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

[image]

Exactly the same code but when I loop it with a separate file, the width does not match the height. And, I am just curious why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"flex-nowrap" does not let items to go to next row, if total width of all items and gaps does not fit container width, so flex needs to fit all 6 items in one row, so it shrinks their width.

Comment: Oh man. Spent 4 hours figuring out why and this was just one code. Cheers.

Comment: How can I keep 400x400 size and make it horizontally scrollable??

Comment: `overflow-x: auto;` in css should work